# What is the radius of convergence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{2n-1}/a_{n}$

What is the radius of convergence?

Ps: I found that $\limsup|1/a_{n}|^{1/n}=1/6$

But I am confused because of $x^{2n-1}$

What is the radius of convergence?

Comment: What is the radius of convergence? Help me! @julien

Comment: What is $a_n$? How can you calculate $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}|1/a_n|^{1/n}=1/6$$ without having a definition for $a_n$?

Comment: This is a part of my question. I calculate. Here is not important. I ask you $x^{2n-1}$ ? @clayton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sum should start at $n=1$. Otherwise, this is not a power series.

Then the radius of convergence of your series is the same as the one of 
$$
\sum\frac{x^{2n}}{a_n}=\sum\frac{y^n}{a_n}
$$
with $y=x^2$.

If you found $\limsup |1/a_n|^{1/n}=1/6$, this means that the $y$ power series has radius $6$.

Therefore, the $x$ power series has radius $\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: Thank you so much again and again:))

Comment: i am confused. but I ask $x^{2n-1}$. Is not important this (-1)?

Comment: No, it is not important. Note that your sum should start at $n=1$ to get an actual power series. For $x=0$, this converges anyway. For $x\neq 0$, $\sum x^{2n-1}/a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum x^{2n}/a_n$ converges. Since you simply pass from one to the other by multiplying or dividing by $x$.

Comment: Hmm ok! I have understood. Thank you for help.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not downvote. I dont understand... Ps shows so. Also I make tick.

Comment: @B11 Sure, not you. But someone downvoted and I was just curious.

Comment: hmm ok. Hopefully you will learn the reason for the downvote.